# Can't install Ubuntu or Fedora from USB flash drive

Tags: ubuntu, usb, installation, bootable-media

My previous problem was describe here: [Can't boot OS from USB drive, showing black screen with blinking cursor](https://superuser.com/questions/254909/cant-boot-os-from-usb-drive-showing-black-screen-with-blinking-cursor) and there are informations about my laptop. Please look there and then read rest here.

I changed flash drive and it fixed the problem but now when I boot to Ubuntu (or I tried Fedora, it does same) I can't install system. When I click on Install Ubuntu 10.10, I choose language, then on next window I click Forward but it just show waiting cursor and nothing happens (same with Fedora). It doesn't freeze so I can end install and I can take screenshot (when I was taking the screen, cursor was shown as waiting, not normal as in picture, it's weird).

[image: Image where my installation ends]

I think there is some problem with "Disk and Volumes" and so. But I used `chkdsk` from Windows 7 on boot and it said everything is all right. I tried utility in Ubuntu to check filesystem and it is all right too.

[image: Image with my Disk (Volumes and other things)]

Comment: There's a crash icon in the tray (the 1st one on the left) - what is it?

Comment: It was problem with drivers to graphic card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to do is to verify md5 hash of the Ubuntu iso file you downloaded. md5sum on Linux, FCIV [Availability and description of the File Checksum Integrity Verifier utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290) on Windows. The hash should be listed on [UbuntuHashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes).

Comment: I check md5 has and it´s ok. It show same as on UbuntuHashes (1b9df87e588451d2ca4643a036020410 for ubuntu-10.10-desktop-amd64.iso). As I said, I used Fedora too and it looks like same problem. I think that .iso files are all right.

Comment: @Biblo Sorry my advice was of no use. But at least bad iso is ruled out :)

Comment: no problem, I think that apps like unetbootin or universal usb installer checks iso for md5 hash but now we are sure that there is no problem with this.

Comment: @Biblo I don't think they check, because you can customize the iso before creating bootable usb. How could they know if you did it or not? Besides I personally tried install Ubuntu from usb stick with bad iso :)